# jquery ui slider + updating min & max

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working on this demo: [www.datesitesfree.com.au](http://www.datesitesfree.com.au)

There are 2 numbers below the slider 18 and 99...

I need to have a range slider (2 movable parts) and the min needs to update the 18 value and max needs to update the 99 value.eg:

[image]

Any advice on how to get the 2 moving parts and how to get them to update the 2 values separately?

Here is the current HTML:

```
    <h2 class="demoHeaders">Slider</h2>
    <div id="slider"></div>
    </br></br>
    <span id="minAge">18</span>
    </br></br>
    <span id="maxAge">99</span>
```

And here is the current JQUERY:

```
            $('#slider').slider({
                min: 18,
                max: 99,
                change: function(event, ui) {
                    $('span#minAge').html(ui.value);
                }
            });
```

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have a double slider, you need to set range: true and values: [start, end].

So for your code:

```
            $('#slider').slider({
                range: true,
                min: 18,
                max: 99,
                values: [18, 99],
                change: function(event, ui) {
                    $('span#minAge').html(ui.values[0]);
                    $('span#maxAge').html(ui.values[1]);
                }
            });
```